# org.hibernate.queryexception error while executing HQL Query

Tags: java, hibernate, db2, hql, rank

I am executing the query in HQL for which i am getting the below error. I am using **DB2** as database,

```
Error: Caused by:  org.hibernate.queryexception: in expected  [hql query]
```

and query is,

```
final String qStr = "select distinct a.* from (select attr.* from AttributeModel attr, BOModel bo, BusinessIdentifierModel ident, NameTransferModel name, NameTransferModel name2 WHERE" +
                                    "bo.businessIdentifierId = ident.businessIdentifierId AND" +
                                    "ident.businessIdentifier = :businessIdentifier AND" +
                                    "attr.compAttributeModelKey.boRowNo = bo.compBOModelKey.boRowNo AND" +
                                    "attr.compAttributeModelKey.eventId = bo.compBOModelKey.eventId AND" +
                                    "bo.typeId = name.nameTransferId AND" +
                                    "name.originalName = :className AND" +
                                    "bo.nameId = name2.nameTransferId AND" +
                                    "name2.originalName = :fieldName) a JOIN (SELECT event.eventId, attr2.nameTransferId, attr2.compAttributeModelKey.boRowNo, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY bo2.businessIdentifierId, attr2.nameTransferId, attr2.compAttributeModelKey.boRowNo ORDER BY event.eventId desc ) rank from EventModel event, BOModel bo2, AttributeModel attr2,BusinessIdentifierModel ident  WHERE" +
                                                                        "event.changeTime <= :time AND" +
                                                                        "bo2.businessIdentifierId = ident.businessIdentifierId AND"+
                                                                        "bo2.compBOModelKey.eventId = event.eventId AND" +
                                                                        "attr2.compAttributeModelKey.eventId = event.eventId AND" +
                                                                        "attr2.compAttributeModelKey.boRowNo = bo2.compBOModelKey.boRowNo AND" +
                                                                        "ident.businessIdentifier = :businessIdentifier) b ON (" +
                                                                        "a.eventId = b.eventId AND" +
                                                                        "a.nameTransferId = b.nameTransferId AND" +
                                                                        "a.boRowNo = b.boRowNo AND" +
                                                                        "RANK = '1')";
```

Please have a glance and suggest me if any wrong syntax

Comment: ...I'd guess it's complaining about the fact that you don't have spaces after `WHERE` and `AND` keywords?  Regardless, shouldn't you have more of a message from the exception?  Is there more to the stack trace?

Comment: Thanks Clockwork-Muse, i have tried giving spaces. But still i am getting same exception. Please tell me is there any wrong syntax?

Comment: Then please update the example here to reflect that.  A really quick glance doesn't reveal anything obviously wrong, but I want the rest of the stack trace for a better explanation from the engine.  It _has_ to have more to the message.

Answer (score 0):

The (first) error is actually in the message...

```
Error: Caused by:  org.hibernate.queryexception: **in** expected  [hql query]
```

An IN is expected.

I don't really understand your join.
Your JOIN on the second subselect, is that supposed to be where IN?